# Map to for loop

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, command-line

How can I make a mapping that includes a for-loop?

```
xnoremap <leader>y :for i in [1, 2, 3, 4] | echo i | endfor
```

errors `E121: Undefined variable: i`

and

```
xnoremap <leader>y :for line in getlines(1, 2) | echo line | endfor
```

errors `E588: :endfor without :for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help :bar` is help for the `|` pipe line separator

You need to escape them to use them in arguments:

```
xnoremap <leader>y :for i in [1, 2, 3, 4] \| echo i \| endfor
```